# Change score based on score of killed player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a PvP server with player classes and money, and I want to award players money based on the class of the player they killed. (Both are scores.)

Comment: Hmm... This actually might be possible with a `scoreboard players operation` command, but I'm not completely familiar with how that actually works, unfortunately

Comment: `+=` mode might work with a "money increase" score, but I still need to detect the killer and the killed.

Comment: Have you tried any commands yourself? Showing some effort first may be a good idea.

Comment: Nope. I'm still setting up some PvP maps.

Comment: So if a player were to kill ten people he could buy a rank for ten dollars and then if a player killed the ranked player they got twice the amount of money to buy a better rank, or something like that?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Maybe `/testforblock` testing for the output of the command block that set the score of that player?

Comment: Hmm... yeah, figuring out whose score to increment and the appropriate value is going to be tricky. You could detect it by detecting when a player's playerKills score goes up and when a player's deaths score goes up, but there are so many edge cases involved there it probably wouldn't be totally reliable

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this only works by using colored nametags and teams. If you cannot allow those, or are already using them, this solution will not work*

These examples use two classes, but they are rather tesselable:

Create the teams:

```
/scoreboard teams add c1
/scoreboard teams option c1 color red (you can change the 'red')
/scoreboard teams add c2
/scoreboard teams option c2 color blue (you can change the 'blue')
```

Create the scoreboard variables:

```
/scoreboard objectives add killc1 teamkill.red (same as above)
/scoreboard objectives add killc2 teamkill.blue (same as above)
/scoreboard objectives add constants dummy
/scoreboard players set ten constants 10
/scoreboard players set twenty constants 20
(if not yet done:)
/scoreboard objectives add money dummy
```

At the end of the game, run these commands in order to update the money:

```
/scoreboard players operation @a killc1 *= ten constants
/scoreboard players operation @a killc2 *= twenty constants
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @p money += @p killc1
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @p money += @p killc2
```

Comment: Should work for the solo mode, but won't work for the team mode (but I'll figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

This here is a very simple setup that will add the recently deceased player's `value` score to the recent killer's `money` score. "Recent" in this context means "in the last tick". The chances of two players being killed in the very same game tick are extremely low, therefore I won't take that into account.

First, set up a couple of objectives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add kills playerKillCount
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
/scoreboard objectives add money dummy
/scoreboard objectives add value dummy
```

Whenever a player chooses a class, run

```
/scoreboard players add @a money 0
/scoreboard players set @a[<class selector>] value <value for class>
```

The first command will add 0 money to every player. This important since players without *any* score (rather than 0) cannot be affected by operations.

Place a repeat/chain line of command blocks and have it run

```
/scoreboard players operation @a[score_kills_min=1,c=1] money += @a[score_deaths_min=1,c=1] value
/scoreboard players set @a[score_deaths_min=1] deaths 0
/scoreboard players set @a[score_kills_min=1] kills 0
```

The first command will simply fail if a killing and killed player don't exist in this tick.

---

*Bonus*: The `value` score works on a player by player basis. This makes it easy to add a bounty system (e.g. bonus money for ending a killing spree) by simply adjusting a player's `value`.